# Both DocTest and Catch 2 not running unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, resharper, doctest, catch2

I'm starting a new win32 C++ project using Visual Studio 2019 (v. 16.0.4) and Resharper (v. 2019.1.1) and can't get either the Catch2 or Doctest unit testing framework to run a test.  I prefer Doctest and used that first and when that didn't work, I tried Catch2 and had the same result.  Both frameworks find the test, but give the status "Inconclusive Test not run".  The Catch2 warning states: "2019.05.19 08:47:46.447    WARN Element CatchTest Test was left pending after its run completion.
".  All the code below is for Catch2:

**Engine.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "pch.h";
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>;

int  wWinMain( dv* ghInst, dv* ghPrevInst, dv* gupCmdLine, dsd gsdCmdShowFlag);

int test();
```

**Engine.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
//#include "..\DocTest_2_2_2.h"
#include "..\Catch_2_7_2.h"
#include "Engine.h"


int wWinMain( dv* ghInst, dv* ghPrevInst, dv* gupCmdLine, dsd gsdCmdShowFlag) {
  return 0;
  };


int test() { return 3; }

TEST_CASE("CatchTest Test") {

  REQUIRE(test() == 3);
}
```

**DocTest.cpp** (Using Catch2 code, DocTest code is commented out)

```
#include "pch.h"

//#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT
//#include "..\DocTest_2_2_2.h"

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "..\Catch_2_7_2.h"
```

I found that there was an issue like this on conversations about prior versions of Visual Studio and Resharper but I'm using the latest versions and still have a problem.

In Resharper options, I have "Enable Catch support" selected under "C++ Tests" and also have "Enable MSTest support" selected under "MsTest".  I have the x64 architecture selected for both the unit tests and on all project configuration settings.

Any help with this is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `wMinMain` does not run the tests. See [doctest docs](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/main.md) on how to provide a correct `main` entry point.